# Sublime Text 3 : How to display the line numbers of the evaluated lines in REPL Python?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

using Sublime-Text-3

When i evaluate some selected python code, in PEPL Python (with SublimeREPL), i get something like that:

*>>> print("thank you")

thank you*

(i already set, "show_transferred_text": true,)

Instead of send and see the whole code that evaluated, i would like to see the line numbers of this evaluated code. Have you any ideas about this ?
(for example to display sth like this: >>> evaluated lines (1:30))

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible with the default install of SublimeREPL. Additionally, the project is no longer being maintained, so until someone steps forward to steward the project, this feature won't get added unless you add it yourself. It's all open-source and written in Python.